# How to change the color of a tkinter Checkbox case?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
check2 = tk.Checkbutton(frame1, text = "Checkbox",bg='green',bd=0,fg='blue',highlightthickness=0, 
activeforeground='blue',activebackground='green')
```

How do i change the color of the white case ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the color of the white case"?

Comment: I just expect the white case to have a color (not the text) just the white case to be for example gray ? If it's possible, This is the case that can be checked or not and this case's color is white, I want it to be gray